# Use Bootstrap Modal to confirm action

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form which I wish to submit but once the user clicks the submit button it will show a twitter bootstrap modal which will either let the form continue on to be processed or canceled back to the form page. Is it possible to turn the regular javascript confirm into the bootstrap modal?

```
<form action="http://localhost.testing/modal-processing.php" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="GET">
    <label>Landlord<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
    <select class="form-control input-sm chosen chzn-select" tabindex="1" data-placeholder="Choose a landlord" data-rule-required="true" name="landlord_id" id="landlord_id">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="31" >Liam Lawlor</option>
        <option value="34" >Damian Lavelle</option>
        <option value="35" >Mick Lally</option>
        <option value="36" >Joanne Lavelle</option>
        <option value="37" >Liam Lacey</option>
        <option value="38" >Laura Luney</option>
        <option value="39" >Lenihan Enterprises</option>
    </select>

    <!-- modal caller -->
    <a href="#modal-dialog" class="modal-toggle" data-toggle="modal" data-href="http://localhost.testing/modal-processing.php" data-modal-type="confirm" data-modal-title="Delete Property" data-modal-text="Are you sure you want to delete {$property.address_string}?" data-modal-confirm-url="{$base_url}residential-lettings/properties/do-delete/property/{$property.id}"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Modal Submit</a>

    <!-- proper submit -->
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the Bootstrap modal as a confirm by enabling a link/button (ie:'btnYes') in the modal that is used to trigger form submission via jQuery...

```
$('#btnYes').click(function() {
    // handle form processing here  
    $('form').submit(); 
});
```

Here is a working demo: http://bootply.com/88094

Comment: Very odd. $('form') returns an array, so $('form')[0].submit() does work. This also works: $('#myForm').trigger('submit'). But, alas, your answer is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a click listener to you modal button is correct:

```
$('#myModalButton').click(function(){
  //submit form
  // $('#myForm').submit(); // not working for me
  // $('#myForm')[0].submit(); //works, but is ugly
  $('#myForm').trigger('submit');  //works great
});
```

As far as I can tell, $('form') returns an array. Even $('form#myForm') returns and array.

So,

```
$('form')[0].submit();
```

should work.

```
$('#myForm').trigger('submit');
```

Is the only way I could make it work.